# Using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) on d3 graph gives d3.v6.js:1816 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, graph

I am trying to make the simple line-graph from d3.js example work with JSON instead of a CSV file.

```
    d3.csv(filePath,
    // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
    d => {
        return {date: d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value: d.value}
    }).then(
    // Now I can use this dataset:
    function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
....
```

It fails with an error:  **d3.v6.js:1816 Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,**

For the graph code, see: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_basic.html

How do I make it work with the JSON format ?

Comment: What does your json look like? And are you using d3.json() rather than d3.csv? The data returned by both is a javascript array - so you shouldn't need to stringify and parse.

Comment: It is an array that looks like [{"date":"2020-01-02T05:00:00.000Z","value":"0"},,...]  I want to use d3.json, but the JSON format does not work with the graph, proved by "data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));" line that should not make any error.

Comment: Could you confirm the rest of your code is identical to the linked example? If so, I'll demonstrate an equivalent example with a json data source.

Comment: Yes it is, I am just adding data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); after function(data){... to make sure I can use JSON. This works with other examples, but not the line graphs, probably something to do with the date format, but not sure what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have json data you'll need to use d3.json. While the primary difference between the two is one parses delimited text with column headers, the other parses JSON. A second subtle but in this case key difference is that d3.csv can be provided a row function that formats data row by row, in this case the function the parses the date. We can achieve the equivalent outcome this with d3.json, but we need to wait until after we load the data:

```
d3.json("data.json").then(function(data) {
     data = data.map(function(d) { return { date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value : d.value } });
     ...
```

As seen in this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/7de35043a257435ba32525fe8d84a3d3).

This approach works with d3.csv as well, just that you could use the row function instead:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d) { return { date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value : d.value } })
      .then(function(data) { ...
```

The data returned by d3.csv is a javascript array. The data returned by d3.json is either a javascript array or object. If this is not true then there is a problem with the url, valid csv/json formatting, etc. There is no need to convert the data back to JSON and then back to a JavaScript array/object: this is an unnecessary step, though it should be relatively harmless in most cases.

As for the error you have: you have some SVG path data in the error message, it appears the x value of each coordinate is NaN, which when dealing with graphs and charts is almost always an indicator of:

- a bad x scale,
- bad/missing x values, or
- a mismatch of datatype between scale and data.

In this case, likely caused by the fact that the row function wasn't executed and you were using unparsed dates in scale creation and then scaling.

Comment: What should the JSON look like to make it work with the line graph?  I am still getting an error. Much appreciated!

Comment: This is the [json](https://gist.github.com/Andrew-Reid/7de35043a257435ba32525fe8d84a3d3#file-data-json) I used. I usually run it through something like [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) to double check validity. Date format has to match what you parse of course too.

Comment: My sincere apologies, it took me a long to realize what I was doing wrong. Your answer is right. The example you provided in a comment helped!